# Caching JSON data using text files

Tags: caching, filesystems

I'm trying to have a caching system for my project, the idea is to save the last information (as JSON data) for every user in a text file which exists in a special folder for this user, and instead of hitting the database to fetch the whole required info every time this user logged in or updated the page I call a small field in Users table which called `Uptodate` to decide whether should I update the text file or simply calling the existed one . 
I'm tring to avoid using the memory for chaching data, is this is a good approach to do the job ? should I save data as a text file ? how can I add data to the top of existed file ?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is perfect for what you're trying to do.

localStorage.setItem("json_data", JSONdata);

alert(localStorage.getItem("json_data"));

Comment: How much data can localstorage take for each user ?
is it good for persistent updating ?